# How to implement snake_case for Swagger documentation in spring-boot-starter-data-rest?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-data-rest, springfox

I am using swagger for the documentation of spring-boot-starter-data-rest project. In application.properties file, I have configured: *spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE* naming strategy but unfortunately, I am getting camelCase in swagger documentation. But, the same configuration is working if I change the project from spring-boot-starter-data-rest to spring-boot-starter-web. Below are the dependencies I am using with spring boot 2.1.1.RELEASE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demo1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>demo1</name>
            <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </project>
```

application.properties

```
        spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

package com.example.demo1;

```
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Demo1Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Demo1Application.class, args);

        }

    }
```

SwaggerConfig

```
    package com.example.demo1;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import 
    org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataJacksonConfiguration;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
    import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
    import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
    import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
    import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
    import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    @Import({SpringDataJacksonConfiguration.class})
    public class SwaggerConfig {


        public static ApiInfo metaData(String info) {
            return new ApiInfo(info,
                    "Th",
                    "1.0", "httn.html",
                    new Contact("Thd", "", "thoom"), "decense",
                    "https", new ArrayList());
        }

        @Bean
        public Docket cashFlowApi() {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("-caching").select()
                    .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.demo1"))
                    .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                    .build()
                    .apiInfo(SwaggerConfig.metaData("BOcPI"));
        }
    }
```

StoreController

```
    package com.example.demo1;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiParam;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
    import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


    @RestController
    @CrossOrigin
    public class StoreController {

        @GetMapping(value = "/v1/storeMap")
        @ApiOperation(value = "Returns the list of stores", notes = "Returns the list of stores with pagination.")
        @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved the stores list"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "No content"), @ApiResponse(code = 206, message = "Partial Content"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "A technical error happened")})

        public ResponseEntity<Store> getStore(
                @RequestParam(name = "country_code", required = false) @ApiParam(value = "the code)") String countryCode
                ) {

            return ResponseEntity.ok(new Store(1,"ZZ"));
        }

    }
```

Now with this configuration, in API POST method is expecting snake_case and in the documentation, swagger is showing camelCase. I don't have the option either to change from snake_case to camelCase or spring-boot-starter-data-rest to spring-boot-starter-web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, the issue was with object mapper :

```
    @Configuration
    public class ObjectMapperAutoConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = null;
            for (HttpMessageConverter converter : converters) {
                if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ) {
                    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverter =
                            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter);

                    if (objectMapper == null) {
                        objectMapper = jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper();
                    } else {
                        jacksonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Spring Boot + Swagger project with the same issue, but using Spring the io.swagger packages without the Springfox libraries and using the Gradle plugin [com.benjaminsproule.swagger](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.benjaminsproule.swagger) to generate the docs. So to solve the issue I added this line `ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new ModelResolver(objectMapper))` (it's a hack, I'm not using an official API, but it worked):

```java
package com.company.api;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.converter.ModelConverters;
import io.swagger.jackson.ModelResolver;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Component
public class SwaggerConfig extends ResourceConfig {

  @Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @PostConstruct public void configureSwagger() {
    // Available at localhost:port/swagger.json
    this.register(ApiListingResource.class);
    this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);

    BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
    config.setConfigId("api-springboot-jersey-swagger");
    config.setTitle("Company API");
    config.setResourcePackage("com.company.api");
    config.setPrettyPrint(true);
    config.setScan(true);
    // With this hack we inject into Swagger the same object mapper
    // used by Spring (spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy)
    ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new ModelResolver(objectMapper));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The annotation on the model helped me. @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-snake-to-camel-case

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is best to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. A code example can be very useful. Link-only responses may become invalid if the linked page changes.